# Send additional JSON data along with an existing AJAX post that is sending Serialized Form data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I want to send additional JSON data along with an existing AJAX form post.

I have this AJAX request that submits an HTML form with JavaScript...

```
// Serialize the data in the form
var serializedCommentData = $parentCommentForm.serialize();

// Make AJAX Save POST Request
commentAjaxRequest = $.ajax({
    url: ProjectManagementTaskModal.cache.urlEndPointsObj.createTaskCommentReplyUrl,
    type: 'post',
    data: serializedCommentData
});
```

I also jave a JSON string held in a JavaScript variable...

```
var jsonString = '[{"id":1,"name":"Kenneth Auchenberg","avatar":"http://cdn0.4dots.com/i/customavatars/avatar7112_1.gif","type":"contact","value":"Kenneth Auchenberg"},{"id":9,"name":"Kenneth Hulthin","avatar":"http://cdn0.4dots.com/i/customavatars/avatar7112_1.gif","type":"contact","value":"Kenneth Hulthin"}]';
```

How can I make my JSON string in `var jsonString` be sent with the same AJAX request that the form sends?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make an object with two fields

```
    var pack = { commentData : serializedCommentData, json: jsonString }
```

and serialize it then pass through the data.

```
    commentAjaxRequest = $.ajax({
        url: ProjectManagementTaskModal.cache.urlEndPointsObj.createTaskCommentReplyUrl,
        type: 'post',
        data: JSON.stringify(pack)
    });
```

You will need to unpack in the receiver script

Comment: I have a strange issue.  Simply adding this line of code `var packCommentAndMentions = { commentData2 : serializedCommentData, json2: mentionsJsonyt };` notice the name are not correct so they have no value.  Also when using the correct values that get populated `var packCommentAndMentions = { commentData : serializedCommentData, json: mentionsJson };` in either case after submiting my form it will redirect to a URL with `?new_task_cmt_activity_type=3&new_task_cmt_p....` with the form data in the URL.  If I disable that 1 line then everything goes back to normal.  Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: issue resolved.  It seems a missing var would cause a redirect.   Not sure why though